# Using Pandas df.where on multiple columns produces unexpected NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

Given the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'transformed': ['left', 'right', 'left', 'right'],
    'left_f': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'right_f': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'left_t': [-1, -2, -3, -4],
    'right_t': [-10, -20, -30, -40],
})
```

I want to create two new columns, picking from either `left_*` or `right_*` depending on the content of `transformed`:

```
df['transformed_f'] = df['right_f'].where(
    df['transformed'] == 'right',
    df['left_f']
)

df['transformed_t'] = df['right_t'].where(
    df['transformed'] == 'right',
    df['left_t']
)
```

And I get the expected result

```
df
#    transformed  left_f  right_f  left_t  right_t  transformed_f  transformed_t
# 0  left              1       10      -1      -10              1             -1
# 1  right             2       20      -2      -20             20            -20
# 2  left              3       30      -3      -30              3             -3
# 3  right             4       40      -4      -40             40            -40
```

However when I try to do it in one operation I get an unexpected result containing `NaN` values

```
df[['transformed_f', 'transformed_t']] = df[['right_f', 'right_t']].where(
    df['transformed'] == 'right',
    df[['left_f', 'left_t']]
)

df
#    transformed  left_f  right_f  left_t  right_t  transformed_f  transformed_t
# 0  left              1       10      -1      -10            NaN            NaN
# 1  right             2       20      -2      -20           20.0          -20.0
# 2  left              3       30      -3      -30            NaN            NaN
# 3  right             4       40      -4      -40           40.0          -40.0
```

Is there a way to use `df.where()` on multiple columns at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are close , just add`.values` or `.to_numpy()` with the slice to make it an `NDarray`:

Per docs:

> other : scalar, NDFrame, or callable
>   Entries where cond is False are replaced with corresponding value from other. If other is callable, it is computed on the NDFrame and should return scalar or NDFrame. The callable must not change input NDFrame (though pandas doesn’t check it).

So when you directly input the slice of the dataframe, the indexes(col names) dont match and hence it doesn't update the df, when you pass `.values` , it ignores the indexes and add the values.

```
df[['transformed_f', 'transformed_t']]=(df[['right_f', 'right_t']].
                        where(df['transformed'] == 'right',df[['left_f', 'left_t']].values))
print(df)
```

---

```
  transformed  left_f  right_f  left_t  right_t  transformed_f  transformed_t
0        left       1       10      -1      -10              1             -1
1       right       2       20      -2      -20             20            -20
2        left       3       30      -3      -30              3             -3
3       right       4       40      -4      -40             40            -40
```

Comment: Weird! Do you know the reason for this?

Comment: @NilsWerner i updated my answer with a little more details. Hope that helps

Comment: But the output of the two `where()` variants look exactly the same. They have the exact same index...

Comment: @NilsWerner sorry for my english. the columns are different, so the dictionary replacement doesnt work. Hence we just pull the underlying numpy array to assign