# how to replace (nested) np.where with panda df.where

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, if-statement, where-clause

Nested np.where can replace values based on specified condition. However, as I understand it, df.where (Pandas DataFrame.where) is native to pandas.
Unlike np.where, the df value is returned when the condition is *true* and the specified alternate when *false*.

```py
''' #snippet of data: df_age
     0  1
0   20  3
1   23  4
2   26  5
3   29  2
4   NaN 1
5   NaN 2
6   NaN 3
7   NaN 0
'''
```

```py
## define function to check NaN/null age and assign age
def impute_age(cols):
    age = cols[0] # assign first column to age Series
    #print(f'age: {age}') #debug
    pclass = cols.loc[:,1] # assign 2nd to pclass
    
    '''
    ## Nested np.where that works as expected 
    age_null = np.where((cols[0].isnull()) & (cols[1]==1), 37,
                        np.where((cols[0].isnull()) & (cols[1]==2), 39,
                        np.where((cols[0].isnull()) & (np.logical_or(cols[1] != 1, cols[1] != 2)), 24,   
                                      cols[0]))).astype(int)
    '''
    
    ## nested pd.where
    age_null = age.where((cols[0].notnull()) & ... ... ... )
    
    print(f'age col[0]: \n{age_null}')

impute_age(df_age)
```

Q1: What is the **more pythonic way for the working nested np.where**
Q2: [Main question] How do I write the df.where (age.where) to **achieve the same as the np.where**

NB: I'll be testing out using **mask** at a later stage.
NB: I used nested np.where to replace nested if ...
NB: I'm trying out pd.where, and later mask, map, substitute for demonstration purposes and, at the same time, how best to write them (*pythonically*)

---

NB: I took note of the following:
[SO: df.where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791544/using-pandas-df-where-on-multiple-columns-produces-unexpected-nan-values)
[SO: truth value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)
[np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
[pd.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)
[SO: pd.where col change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71903180/pandas-data-frame-replace-values-in-column-based-on-condition/71903223)
[SO: pd.where nested loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295476/conditional-replacement-and-nested-for-loops-in-python/53366125)
[SO: pd.where covert values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68748948/how-to-convert-non-f-value-into-t/68749114)
[SO: pd.where elif logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74524672/assigning-values-to-multiple-columns-after-applying-elif-logic)
[SO: pd.where nested?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591661/i-wish-to-replicate-conditional-column-from-power-query-m-function-in-python-usi/66607005#66607005)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `np.where/df.where`, let's simplify your code with `map` and `fillna`

Here is the example,

```
s = cols[1].map({1: 37, 2: 39}).fillna(24)
age_null = cols[0].fillna(s)
```

Comment: Thanks @Shubham The .map works like a breeze. #impressive. Two things.   
1. Would you be kind to expatiate further on "don't use df.where (though I kind of see challenges with df.where the more I tried to get it working for the exemplar I'm working on).   
2. Would you mind showing how df.where can be used nonetheless for this exemplar?  
Many thanks